# How to specify specific database to import/convert from in Doctrine (Symfony)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

After digging around, most places use the following command to generate the meta data xml files, for existing databases that we want to import into entities.

> php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml
>   ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm
>   --from-database --force

In my particular project, I use quite a few databases, and specify multiple connections in the doctrine config. Is there a way to specify which database we're targeting for the command above?

Comment: --em=entityManagerName as defined in the config file